# Splitting an argument of a custom macro into a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

### Introduction

I created a simple bus timetable with TikZ:

[image]

Currently, the node placing is done manually.

### The problem

I would like to create an environment which would look approximately like this:

```
\begin{timetable} % optional argument could be [6-21]
    \direction{Sutjeska to Nahorevo:}{6:30,7:15,8:00,9:00}[2em]
\end{timetable}
```

It would:

- draw as much time as is needed -- (rounded up)-1 and (rounded up)+1 for first start time and last start time respectively (for this example 6-10)
- if the optional argument is given, the start time and end time are as given by the argument
- draw the times given in a list at the appropriate place (so 7:15 is `at ($(hour7)!0.25!(hour8)$)`
- `yshift` the direction title and times by the amount given in `\direction{<direction title>}{<timetable>}[<amount>]`

### What I would like to know

How can I split the `<timetable>` argument and perhaps store it some list. I could then probably search for minimum, maximum and calculate appropriate positions for the placing times on the timetable.

Comment: The arguments of `\newcommand` are not the arguments of the macro defined by it, so "`\newcommand` argument" is incorrect here. What you mean is the argument of a custom defined macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the PGF/TikZ macro `\foreach` to loop over the comma separated list. The colon can be split by a macro with a particular parameter text as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\splitcolon#1:#2\relax{%
    % #1 : hour
    % #2 : minutes
    % Do something with them, e.g. store them in macros.
    \def\hour{#1}%
    \def\minutes{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\direction}[2]{%
    \foreach \v in {#2} {%
        % expand \v so that it can be split at the colon:
        \expandafter\splitcolon\v\relax
        % use the values as you wish:
        (\hour)(\minutes)\\ % dummy example
    }%
}

\direction{Sutjeska to Nahorevo:}{6:30,7:15,8:00,9:00}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a list "datatype" in which I could store my hours and minutes (like array, vector, or list)?

Comment: @ipavlic: Not really, just separated lists as strings. See the `etoolbox` package for a few list specific macros.

Comment: @ipavlic: If you _really_ want a "datatype" you could look in to the `pgfoo` object oriented stuff (see the PGF manual, v2.10 or later), but in this case it might be overkill.

Comment: @ipavlic if you really want data types proper, I think LaTeX3 has some capacity, and there's always LuaTeX...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I don't need a datatype for this example, but it could be useful otherwise.

Comment: @ipavlic: and if you need data types which are not provided (yet), just ask a question, and it should come pretty quickly ;-).

Answer (score 2):

TeX allows almost an infinite variety of data structures, but it leaves the methods to manipulate them for you.

For example, this object:

```
\timetable{Nahorevo}{Sutjeska}{12:50,14:45,15:35,16:25}
```

holds information for the route from Nahrorevo to Sutjeska and is an "object" containing two "strings" and a "list".

The most useful data structure is a list and my own preference is to use built-in LaTeX routines for manipulating lists.

We first define a macro to hold information for a route:

```
\def\route#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1#2\endcsname{#1 to #2}
  \expandafter\def\csname#1#2times\endcsname{#3}
}
```

Then we define a macro to loop over the information and print the timetable.

```
\def\timetable#1#2#3{%
  \route{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \def\XX{\csname#1#2times\endcsname}
  \csname#1#2\endcsname\par
  \@for \i:=\XX \do{%
     \i,
   }
}
```

We can then call the two routes as:

```
\timetable{Sutjeska}{Nahorevo}{6:30,7:15,8:00,9:00}\par
\timetable{Nahorevo}{Sutjeska}{12:50,14:45,15:35,16:25}
```

Why I created commands for the routes, is that it is entirely possible that if one had an algorithm for the route Sutjeska->Nahorevo, the Nahorevo->Sutjeska could have been determined automatically, hence creating commands can give you more flexibility in the long run.

The full minimal is shown below,

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \def\route#1#2#3{%
      \expandafter\def\csname#1#2\endcsname{#1 to #2}
      \expandafter\def\csname#1#2times\endcsname{#3}
    }
    \def\timetable#1#2#3{%
      \route{#1}{#2}{#3}
      \def\XX{\csname#1#2times\endcsname}
      \csname#1#2\endcsname\par
      \@for \i:=\XX \do{%
         \i,
       }
    }

   \timetable{Sutjeska}{Nahorevo}{6:30,7:15,8:00,9:00}\par
   \timetable{Nahorevo}{Sutjeska}{12:50,14:45,15:35,16:25}
   \makeatother
   \end{document}
```